# python losing global list contents from child process

Tags: python, list, scope, global

I have a global list that I append to in a child process. Meanwhile the function that called the child process is iterating through the list. When the child process is exited, the global list is empty, even though I appended to it

```
urlsToCheck = list()

def crawler():
    while limit != 0 and urlsToCheck.__len__() > 0:
        curUrl = urlsToCheck.pop(0)
        processLink(curUrl)
        limit -= 1

def processLink(url):
    ...
    for i in validLinks:
        urlsToCheck.append(i)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not shared between processes unless if you use shared data structure explicitly.

See [multiprocessing documentation - Sharing state between processes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).